# Opening modal window in Bootstrap using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm having a problem getting this to work. Pardon my mistakes, I'm really new in AngularJS. This is my code in main app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['duScroll', 'emailModal']);
```

Then, I have this code in my emailModal.module.js file:

```
var mymodal = angular.module('emailModal', []);

mymodal.controller('ModalCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
});

mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
        '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
        '<div class="modal-content">' +
        '<div class="modal-header">' +
        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
        '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace:true,
        scope:true,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.title = attrs.title;

            scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
                if(value == true)
                    $(element).modal('show');
                else
                    $(element).modal('hide');
            });

            $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                });
            });

            $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In my index file, right after the opening body tag I have a div with a controller:

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="ModalCtrl" class="container">
  <modal title="Login form" visible="showModal">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </modal>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#Anchor1" du-smooth-scroll du-scrollspy>Anchor 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Anchor2" du-smooth-scroll du-scrollspy>Anchor 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Anchor3" du-smooth-scroll du-scrollspy>Anchor 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    <div class="navbar-brand img-responsive">
      <img src="assets/img/logo_menu_blank.png" />
    </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="toggleModal()">Open Modal</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

I have tried all possible combinations and was unable to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at UI Bootstrap:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

It's a library which lets you use Bootstrap with Angular in easy and clean way.

---

**UPDATE**

As you are learning Angular, I decided to look closer at your code and run it. Actually, it's working. The only thing I changed was not to add the 'duScroll' module to the app.

You must have forgotten about some detail... Have you added `ng-app="myApp"` to html root element? Did you check if browser console gives you any error?

Comment: ng-app is added to html, and duScroll is handling my anchor navigation, since it'a a one page application. Another issue I have is that the modal is visible at all times, right below my nav. Not hidden at all as it should be.